# Авторизация на passportjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В данном коде passportjs не может найти путь к базе данных с логинами и паролями. Как правильно можно задать путь?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var jade = require('jade');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser("megaultrasupersecret"));
app.use(session({secret: 'my secret'}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

var User = mongoose.model('User', { 
  username: String,
  password: String,
  age: Number
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/registr', function(req, res){
    res.render('registr');
});

app.get('/logged', function(req, res){
  if (req.cookies.cookie) {
    res.render('logged');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});

app.post('/registr', function (req, res, next) {
    new User({ 
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      age: req.body.age
    }).save(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
    res.redirect('/')
});


app.post('/logged',
  passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/logged',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
}));


app.post('/exit', function(req, res) {
    res.clearCookie('cookie', 1337);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('"http://localhost:3000"');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут не лишним было бы дописать в вопросе, какую вы ловите ошибку, но я попробую телепатическим путем.

1. Попробуйте поменять местами кусок с mongoose.connect и созданием модели с куском, где `passport.serialize( ...  ... app.use(passport.session)`
2. проверьте, запущена ли у вас mongo и не шалит ли у вас где-нибудь брандмауэр/файрволл/другие . Получается ли у вас подключится к mongo с помощью какой-нибудь утилиты (Robomongo например)?
3. проверьте под каким пользователем доступна ваша бд, вероятно вам нужно дописать в connection string что-то вроде `mongodb://username:password@localhost/db`. Порт у вас наверняка стандартный, но тоже стоит проверить.
4. Ну и напоследок, вижу знакомые грабли - используйте одинаковый secret для cookieParser и bodyParser, иначе сессия у вас будет порой глючить.